# Helgrind stops program during runtime

Tags: c, pthreads, valgrind

Helgrind freezes during runtime. CTRL+C (`SIGINT`) has to be applied to exit run.

I have written a program that executes correctly and valgrind doesn't report any programs if run in a usual manner without the using `--tool=helgrind`. But when helgrind is used the program stops during runtime.

I haven't found any typichal issues that causes helgrind to behave this way. Got any tips? I couldn't find any issues using `vgdb` either.

**EDIT:** The program is utilizes semaphores and pthreads.

**EDIT:** Adding a bunch of `fprintf` outputs made helgrind work just fine. Why though?

Comment: Can you strip down your code to provide a {mcve] that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: hard to do since the program is pretty big, but i just noticed that if i add some `fprintf ` functions the program works fine. So i guess i need to flush some outputs for some reason...

Comment: When the application is frozen under helgrind, what do you observe with vgdb ? What are your threads doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Using the value of a semaphore as an condition variable is very slow. So since sem_post/sem_wait are atomic operations and helgrind has a "slower check" (non atomic) then my program updates the semaphores way faster then helgrind re-checks the semaphore. And thus freezing helgrind. So a thread-counter or another type of conditional variable fixed the problem.